# Uncaught TypeError Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I got problem error after minify my code, in developer tools  it's notice `Uncaught TypeError: $.totalStorage is not a function` line = `view = $.totalStorage('display');`.

The function for change display product from list to grid. and there are 2 page (search and product) using this function.

As well i know the function is fine (because i not touch it), the problem is the library.

This the function js :

```
function display(view) {
if (view == 'list') {
    $('.product-grid').attr('class', 'product-list');

    $('.product-list > div').each(function(index, element) {
        html  = '<div class="right">';
        html += '<div class="cart">' + $(element).find('.cart').html() + '</div>';
        //html += '  <div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
        html += '<div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';
        html += '</div>';           

        html += '<div class="left">';

        var image = $(element).find('.image').html();

        if (image != null) { 
            html += '<div class="image">' + image + '</div>';
        }

        var price = $(element).find('.price').html();

        if (price != null) {
            html += '<div class="price">' + price  + '</div>';
        }

        html += '<div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
        html += '<div class="description">' + $(element).find('.description').html() + '</div>';

        var rating = $(element).find('.rating').html();

        if (rating != null) {
            html += '<div class="rating">' + rating + '</div>';
        }

        html += '</div>';

        $(element).html(html);
    });     

    $('.display').html('<b><?php echo $text_display; ?></b> <span 

class="showlist"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></span> |  <span class="showgrid"><a onclick="display(\'grid\');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> </span></a></span>');

        $.totalStorage('display', 'list'); 
    } else {
        $('.product-list').attr('class', 'product-grid');

        $('.product-grid > div').each(function(index, element) {
            html = '';

            var image = $(element).find('.image').html();

            if (image != null) {
                html += '<div class="image">' + image + '</div>';
            }

            html += '<div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="description">' + $(element).find('.description').html() + '</div>';

            var price = $(element).find('.price').html();

            if (price != null) {
                html += '<div class="price">' + price  + '</div>';
            }

            var rating = $(element).find('.rating').html();

            if (rating != null) {
                html += '<div class="rating" align=center>' + rating + '</div>';
            }

            html += '<div class="cart">' + $(element).find('.cart').html() + '</div>';
            //html += '<div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';

            $(element).html(html);
        }); 

        $('.display').html('<b><?php echo $text_display; ?></b> <span class="showlist"><a onclick="display(\'list\');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"> </span><?php /*echo $text_list; */?></a></span> | <span class="showgrid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"> </span> <?php /* echo $text_grid; */ ?></span>');

        $.totalStorage('display', 'grid');
    }
}

view = $.totalStorage('display');

if (view) {
    display(view);
} else {
    display('list');
}
```

I using opencart version 1.5.5.1

This is header : (where library call) js in bottom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="<?php echo $direction; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="" />
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<meta name="alexaVerifyID" content="" />
<base href="<?php echo $base; ?>" />
<?php if ($description) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
<?php }else{?>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($keywords) { ?>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
<?php }else{?>
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($icon) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $icon; ?>" rel="icon" />
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach ($links as $link) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $link['href']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $link['rel']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<!-- =================== Stylesheet =================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/combine-style.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/responsive.css" />

<!-- COMBINE = combine-style.min.css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/mobile-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/owl.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/owl.transitions.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/slicknav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/popup.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/responsive.css" />
-->
<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
<link rel="<?php echo $style['rel']; ?>" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $style['href']; ?>" media="<?php echo $style['media']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>


<!-- =================== Javascript  =================== -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<?php foreach ($scripts as $script) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $script; ?>"></script>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($stores) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php foreach ($stores as $store) { ?>
$('body').prepend('<iframe src="<?php echo $store; ?>" style="display: none;"></iframe>');
<?php } ?>
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '916337951821710');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=916337951821710&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
<?php echo $google_analytics; ?>
</head>
<body id="top">

<!--<span class="visible-xs">SIZE XS</span><span class="visible-sm">SIZE SM</span><span class="visible-md">SIZE MD</span><span class="visible-lg">SIZE LG</span>-->
<!--facebook widget -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
setTimeout( function () {
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.async=true;
  js.defer=true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}, 3000);
</script> 
<!-- end fb widget code --> 

<!-- top notification -->
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="topbarinfo col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8"><i class="fa fa-phone textorangeBK iconsize16"></i>  Hubungi Kami : 021 - 6124788 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-map-marker textorangeBK iconsize16"></i> <i class="fa fa-envelope textorangeBK iconsize16"></i>  </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="top-links"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>">My Account</a> | <a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>">Checkout</a> | <a href="http://jualbeli.com/index.php?route=information/confirmpayment">Konfirmasi Pembayaran</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="body-wrap">
<!-- start logo -->
<div id="header" class="logo-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <?php if ($logo) { ?>
        <div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <div class="search-wrap">
          <div class="rowx">
            <div id="search" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 search-input-wrap">
              <div class="button-search">Search</div>
              <input class="inputsearch" type="text" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 cart-wraper">
              <div> <?php echo $cart; ?> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- start menu -->
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="menu" class="col-md-12 menu-inner menu-nav">
        <ul class="nav-effect">
          <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>">Home</a></li>
          <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
            <!-- 060115 --><a class="drop"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
            <?php if ($category['children']) { 
            $count_cat_chld = count($category['children']);
            ?>
              <!-- 060115 --><div class="sub-menu"> 
              <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $count_cat_chld;) { ?>
              <ul>
                <?php $j = $i + ceil($count_cat_chld / $category['column']); ?>
                <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
                <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <!--hide.js-->
            <?php } ?>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/combine-min2.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/script.js"></script>
<!--
COMBINE = combine-min2.js
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui-tabs-rotate.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/external/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/default/popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/hide.js"></script>
-->
<div id="notification"></div>
```

(Error only in product, search is fine)

if i put `jquery.1.9.1.min.js` in bottom the search will be error (notice is same).
I not good in `jquery` so i already try restore (before combine/minify) or change the line,  but result it's still same.

Does anyone have any ideas for fix this?

Comment: remove your comments before minifying it

Comment: @Arif: Any minifier that you have to do that for is a minifier you shouldn't be using.

Comment: The listed content of `combine-min2.js` does not have any `jquery.total-storage.min.js` file, which I believe is the default file for jQuery totalStorage plugin. Is it included in the project with another name or somewhere else than the header, or is it simply missing?